# How do I keep CFEXECUTE from hanging after a PrintStackTrace

Tags: java, coldfusion, cfexecute

I'm using ColdFusion MX7 to perform a CFEXECUTE on some Java 6 code.

Unfortunately, since CF7 does not work under JDK 6 I must do it this way.

My problem is that when an exception happens in the Java code if I call a `printStackTrace` on the exception the CFEXECUTE command hangs.  ColdFusion eventually times out but the Java process continues to hang in the background.

I'm guessing there is some blocking going on but I can't seem to figure out why.

If I don't do a `printStackTrace` then everything works fine.

The exceptions are WebService exceptions generated with JAXWS from the Oracle Information Rights Management wsdl.

**EDIT**

I noticed that I am able to call the `printStackTrace` with a file `PrintStream` as a parameter and it works fine.  So, it looks like the error stream is having troubles.

Here is the Java Code:

```
public void Execute(){
    AdminUtils AU = AdminUtils.GetInstance();

    AccountServicesPort AA = AU.GetAccountServicesPort(); 

    LicenseServerRef LicSerRef = AU.GetLicenseServerRef();

    User UserToSave = new User();
    UserToSave.setUserName(UserName);
    UserToSave.setFirstName(FirstName);
    UserToSave.setLastName(LastName);
    UserToSave.setEmailAddress(EmailAddress);
    UserToSave.setServer(LicSerRef);

    try{
        AU.LogMessage("Change User: " + UserName + " " + FirstName + " " + LastName + " " + EmailAddress);
        AA.saveChangesToUser(UserToSave);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is the ColdFusion call:

```
<!--- Update the IRM User. --->
<CFEXECUTE name="c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\javaw.exe"
           arguments="-cp C:\CFusionMX7\Externals\IRM.jar;C:\CFusionMX7\Externals\Config IRMWebServices.UpdateUser #LoginID# #NewFname# #NewLname#"
           timeout="15" 
           variable="OUTPUT">
</CFEXECUTE>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `e.printStackTrace();` writes to stderr (standard error stream). Since `cfexecute` does not capture stderr, that is probably what is causing cfexecute to hang. There was a patch to fix this behavior in CF8.

Since you are using 7, try Ben Forta's tips about:

- Redirecting stderr to stdout: [A Couple Of  Gotchas](http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2006/9/11/A-Couple-Of-CFEXECUTE-Gotchas)
- Flags to run commands and terminate upon completion: [Using CFEXECUTE To Execute Command Line Utilities](http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2006/7/31/Using-CFEXECUTE-To-Execute-Command-Line-Utilities)

Using both `/c` and `2>&1` should get rid of the hanging problem.

**Update: Added Example**

*ColdFusion Code:*

```
<cftry>  
    <cfset argString = '/c "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin\java.exe" -cp c:\myJar.jar TestStdErr 2>&1'  >  
    <cfexecute name="c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe" 
        arguments="#argString#"    
        outputFile="c:\cfexcuteResults.log" 
        timeout="5" />  
    <cfcatch>  
       <cfdump var="#cfcatch#">  
    </cfcatch>  
</cftry>
```

*Java Class:*

```
public class TestStdErr {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // cause a divide by zero exception 
            int a = 0;
            int b = 2 /a;
         }
         catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I found these earlier.  The problem isn't that I need the err stream info.  It just hangs when the trace is printed to it.

Comment: I believe the fact that stderr is not captured, is part of what is causing cfexecute to hang. Try using both flags /c and 2>&1, and it should get rid of the hanging problem.